# How to put telebot function inside a thread ? python

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling, telegram-bot, telebot

i want to run this function in while loop to update the time always (its like an alarm system)

Here is a piece of the code:

```
def azan(message):
timed1 = ('17:52')
timed2 = ('22:09')
#print(timed2) #for testing
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"test ☾")
while True:
    jt = datetime.now(tz)
    time_now = (jt.strftime(dt_format))
    #print('azan on') #for testing
    if timed1 == time_now:
        print ("[☾] It is time for Al Fajr prayer ")
        sleep (60)
    if timed2 == time_now:
        print ("[☾] It is time for Al thar prayer ")
        sleep (60)
MainFun_Run = threading.Thread(target=MainFun) #to run the rest of the code
MainFun_Run.start()

azan_run = threading.Thread(target=azan) #to worn me if time has become == [timed1]
azan_run.start()
```

the problem is when i run it like this i get that error:

```
TypeError: azan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

and when edit it to be like this: `azan_run = threading.Thread(target=azan(message))` i got this error `NameError: name 'message' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
threading.Thread(target=azan,args=(message,)).start()
```

Comment: still the same "NameError: name 'message' is not defined"